# Ultrasonic sensor 960KHz reading with arduino or any other SBC

Tags: arduino

I have an ultrasonic sensor pair which I bought from https://hacktronics.co.in/water-flow-meter-sensor/ultrasonic-flowmeter-sensor.
The sensor is of 960khz... I wish to make water flow measurement inside a pipe from it using any sbc preferably Arduino. the sensor has only two wires VCC and GND, hence I am not able to get as to how to interface it with an SBC or make a sensor pin...

Comment: OK that's the back story, so what is the question?

Comment: to make a sensor pin that can read the reflected rays

Comment: Arduino isn't an SBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to design the whole driver circuit. I think this can help you

[A Sensitive DIY Ultrasonic Range Sensor](http://www.kerrywong.com/2011/01/22/a-sensitive-diy-ultrasonic-range-sensor/)

Comment: links tend to die so can you put up **an actual answer** based on this link.

Comment: Can a 960 kHz transducer be used to measure waterflow inside an iron pipe with a diameter of 6 inch?